# how to grab user edition from numerous swing components?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a JFrame with a bunch of different JTextField and so on. How to collect data entered by user, without setting actions for each of this components?

Note: I create this JTextField using "inline" code, like this:

```
    layout.row().grid(new JLabel("Density")).add(new JTextField("1"))
            .spanRow();
    layout.row().grid(new JLabel("Minimal size"))
            .add(new JTextField("1")).spanRow();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to iterate through the child elements of each container, check if it is an instance of `JTextField` and then read the contents using the `getText` method.

Comment: Ok, that would be fine, but how to let my iterating code know, what editor it deals with?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, I'm sorry.  Are you asking how to uniquely identify the component you are reading from?

Comment: Yes, If I iterate through the child elements, as you answered, then how to identify where to put values read?

Comment: You could use the hash code for the text field, or find the corresponding label text?

Answer (score 1):

The [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class has some convenience methods that makes this easy:

```
List<JTextField> components = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JTextField.class, container, true);

for (JTextField component: components)
{
    // add custom code here
}
```